# Lambda-Calculus Representation in NLTK CCG

Tags: python, nltk, lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I am trying to implement a probabilistic ccg with lambda-calculus features.

Basically i want to do the following code:

```
>> lex = parseLexicon(r'''
 :- S,NP
 He => NP {sem=\x.he(x)} [1.0]
 Walks => S\NP {sem=\X. walk(X)} [1.0]
 There => S\S {sem=\x . there(x)} [1.0]
 ''')
>> parser = CCGChartParser(lex)
>> all_parses = parser.nbest_parse(“He walks 
there”.split(),n=100)
>> for parse in all_parses: 
 printCCGDerivation(parse)
```

but existing CCG implementation of NLTK does not support {sem=\x.he(x)} [1.0] kinds of semantic parts in lexicon.

Are there Any other CCG implementations that can handle this?
Or can i represent this inside of NLTK?

Comment: I am curious if you ever found a solution to your question?

Comment: @crackjack no, unfortunaltely.  there were a master thesis project implementation on this but it is not completed. i contacted with thesis advisor, he said project is  no longer maintaned.

Comment: I'm that guy. The semantics predicate was recently implemented. The probabilistic parsing for CCG is on the horizon. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLTK CCG recently supports semantics predicate (Lambda-Calculus representation) computation. Please see the tests here: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/test/ccg_semantics.doctest

The probabilistic parsing for CCG is on the horizon: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1356

Comment: I do appreciate your answer after all that time. thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is just a parser, but for full functionality we will need wide coverage lexicon?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately no, this does not exist yet. I too have been looking at this space.
It seems to be in the works mentioned here on their wiki - 
Semantic-Parsing

If you are interested in other languages / frameworks, take a peek at [Semantic Parsing with Execution, Stanford](https://github.com/percyliang/sempre) or [The University of Washington Semantic Parsing Framework](https://bitbucket.org/yoavartzi/spf).

If you want to build something from the ground up, you might want to obtain the CCGBank or revive C&C Tools.

Most of the above is in Java, but I have seen [attempts to parse the C&C Marked file in Python](http://github.com/syllog1sm/ccg).

I personally would like to see CCG come to Node.js.

Comment: Thanks for you info. I checked the page where I can download CCGBank (the linguistic data consortium site, https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/ldc2005t13) but it seems I will be charged to obtain.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind switching to Common LISP, there is a ccg tool (CCGlab) developed by Cem Bozsahin. It also has PCCG training. https://github.com/bozsahin/ccglab